# How to find the highest and the lowest number and its position in a bidimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new here.
I'm beginning studying programming and C++.
I have to do a program that requests numbers to the user to fill an array, and then a function to find the highest and the lowest value and its position in the array.
This is what I have now, it works to find the highest number and its position, but it does not work to find the lowest, the lowest value that has found isn't correct and either its position:

```
int main() {
    int array[SIZEF][SIZEC];
    int zero = 0;
    int highest[0][0];  //to find the highest, array from 0 value.
    int lowest[0][0];   //to find the lowest, takes the highest value and then compare, if its lower than the current value of the array, it takes its value 

    highest[0][0] = zero;

    fill_array(array, SIZEF, SIZEC);

    highlow(array, SIZEF, SIZEC, highest, lowest);

    getchar();

    return 0;
}

void fill_array(int array[][SIZEC], int sizef, int sizec) {
    //code to fill the array, no problem here.    
}

void highlow(int array[][SIZEC], int sizef, int sizec, int highest[][0], int lowest[][0]) {
    int positionX = 0;
    int positionY = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizef; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizec; j++) {
            if (array[i][j] > highest[0][0]) {
                //if the current value of the array is higher than highest value, highest value takes its value.
                highest[0][0] = array[i][j];
                positionX = i;
                positionY = j;
                lowest[0][0] == highest[0][0]; //now lowest value its the highest value

                if (array[i][j] < lowest[i][j]) { //so, if current array value its lower than lowest value
                                                  //lowest value takes its value.                
                    lowest[0][0] = array[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much. (excuse my english, i'm learning too).

Comment: Plàcid Masvidal, What compiler and settings are you using that did not warn about `int highest[0][0];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int highest[0][0];  //to find the highest, array from 0 value.
int lowest[0][0];   //to find the lowest, takes the highest value and then compare, if its lower than the current value of the array, it takes its value
```

You are declaring arrays of zero length. If you simply want to save the highest and lowest value, why not use a simple integer instead? So:

```
int highest = 0;
int lowest = 0;
```

Those two values should be set to the first value of the multi-dimensional array at the beginning of main. After that you can loop through the array and compare the current array element to the previously highest and lowest value. So at the beginning of main:

```
highest = array[0][0];
lowest = array[0][0];
```

Furthermore you will need separate parameters for the position of the highest and the lowest values:

```
int positionX_highest = 0;
int positionY_highest = 0;
int positionX_lowest = 0;
int positionY_lowest = 0;
```

Your loops should be fine. However the comparison inside the loops need to be separated. The if query for the lowest value is never executed in your code. Check the conditions separately:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizef; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sizec; j++) {
      if (array[i][j] > highest) 
      {
            //If the current array element is higher than the highest so far, save it
            highest = array[i][j];
            positionX_highest = i;
            positionY_highest = j;
      }
      if (array[i][j] < lowest)
      {
            //If the current array element is lower than the lowest so far, save it
            lowest = array[i][j];
            positionX_lowest = i;
            positionY_lowest = j;
      }
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> int highest[0][0];  //to find the highest, array from 0 value.
>
> int lowest[0][0];   //to find the lowest, takes the highest value and then compare, if its lower than the current value of the array, it takes its value
> ```

these two array allow to contains 0 elements, the dimensions are 0 (note that ISO C forbids zero-size array)

so in

```
highest[0][0]=zero;
```

you write out of the array, and like every where after you have access out of these 2 arrays

why did you not sized them as *array* ? I say that because of `lowest[i][j]` elsewhere in your program even that seems strange

---

if I forget the problem about the dimension of these two vectors, in

```
lowest[0][0]==highest[0][0];
```

that statement does nothing, may be you wanted

```
lowest[0][0]=highest[0][0];
```

? even that seems strange

---

if I forget the problem about the dimension of these two vectors, in

```
if(array[i][j] < lowest[i][j])
```

you never write in lowest except in `[0][0]`  so `lowest[i][j]` is undefined except when i and j are 0

---

You call `fill_array` and `highlow` in *main* while there are not declared/defined because they are defined after *main*, the compiler will use a default declaration from your calls, this is dangerous, move them before *main* or declara them before *main*

---

About dimensions :

`int a[10]` allows to store 10 int, the indexes are 0 .. 9

`int highest[2][3]` allows to store 2*3 = 6 int, first index is 0..1 and second 0..2

etc

your array allow to store 0*0 = 0 elements, is you only need to access to `highest[0][0]` you need to define them like `int highest[1][1];` and same for the other array, but in that case what is the interrest ? you just need an int var, not an array

I encourage you need to read book/tutorial about the C language

I also encourage you to request high level of warning/error when you compile, for instance if you use *gcc* do `gcc -pedantic -Wall ....`

Comment: Note: 0 is not a valid array size in standard C.  "it shall have a value greater than zero"  C11 §6.7.6.2 1